# Word wrap break word for one word only?

Tags: html, css

I want to use `word-wrap: break-word` for just one word inside an element. If I use it for the whole element then it looks messy. I did a search but could not find if and how to do it, is it possible?

I had something like the below in mind, but that didnt work obviously.

```
<a href="http://www.gnruoegvnuergvneginvjn9ege494jqj049ijirtg9g994w90409gngioeiegioi34ioiginioe5inigo5jgo5iojgio5iowgiowjmvmq.com" target="_blank" style="word-wrap: break-word;">http://www.gnruoegvnuergvneginvjn9ege494jqj049ijirtg9g994w90409gngioeiegioi34ioiginioe5inigo5jgo5iojgio5iowgiowjmvmq.com</a>
```

Comment: Whats the required output?

Comment: I sincerely hope that's not an actual url :P

Comment: Well, you just encapsulate that word with `<span>` tags and apply style to it.

Comment: @Pardeep Dhingra - Basically that the URL stays within the width of my responsive container and does not go overboard.

Comment: @odedta - Hi, thank you, that was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code. I hope this is what you are asking for ( just to wrap a single word )

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <a href="http://www.gnruoegvnuergvneginvjn9ege494jqj049ijirtg9g994w90409gngioeiegioi34ioiginioe5inigo5jgo5iojgio5iowgiowjmvmq.com" target="_blank" style="word-wrap: break-word;">http://www.gnruoegvnuergvneginvjn9ege494jqj049ijirtg9g994w90409gngioeiegioi34ioiginioe5inigo5jgo5iojgio5iowgiowjmvmq.com</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Hi my naame is
    <a href="#" style="word-wrap:break-word"> HelloWOrldHelloWOrldHelloWOrldHelloWOrld </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/oyLfjd23/1/) link

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `break-word` is legal. Have you tried `break-all`?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp